# Restricting number of object returned by breeze query (security point of view)

Tags: .net, security, breeze

Suppose there are 200 records of employee whose last name starts with p, then following breeze query returns 200 records. This will take huge bandwidth. I can modify the following code to fetch only 10 records and thus saving bandwidth. But malicious user can run the following query in his browser to throttle the bandwidth. Am looking for server side solution to limit the record for only top 10 records.

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from("Employees")
    .orderBy("LastName")
    .where("LastName", "startsWith", "P");
```

And I have BreezeController in .NET code as follows.

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<EmployeeDBContext>  _contextProvider = ...

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Employee>Employee()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Sessions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by limiting the maximum records on server side using `PageSize` attribute:

```
  [HttpGet]
    [BreezeQueryable(PageSize=10)]
    public IQueryable<Employee>Employee()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Sessions;
    }
```